# Extend lower thirds title

Tags: premiere, animation, pro

I am quite new to premiere pro. I started creating own lower thirds for Interview questions, but then used a template I found online (since it looks much better). https://mixkit.co/free-premiere-pro-templates/lower-third-in-a-text-box-280/

I was able to customize the template for my needs, but could´t change the length. So the questions fly in, stay there for very short time, and fly back. Does anyone know, how I can make them stay longer, without changing the speed of moving in and out? Couldn't find any keyframes as well. Help is much appreciated.